# How to get AsyncStorage value from outside of function

Tags: react-native

I want to access my token from **ACCESS_TOKEN** . and merge to my URL.

```
async getToken(){
try{
var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN')
}catch(error){}
return token;
};

componentDidMount(){
var v = this.getToken()
Alert.alert(v)
return fetch('http://localhost/'+v);
}
```

I get the error in the output.

> com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be casst to java.lang.string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the async and await in `componentDidMount` as well as `getToken` returns a promise (as with all functions declare with `async`).

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let v = await this.getToken();
```

Comment: it works but `let` does not return the value.so I changed it to `var` is that ok?

Comment: I'd recommend `const` but if `let` doesn't work then that probably wont either. No idea why it wouldn't work, might be something else wrong with your code.